# Why is wp_kses not keeping style attributes as expected?

Tags: tags, formatting, wp-kses

I want to keep the style attribute. $str is just an example, here's my code:

```
$allowed_html = array(
     'div' => array(
         'title' => array(),
         'class' => array(),
         'style' => array()
    )
);

$str = '<div title='Click to continue' style='display:table'>This is a button</div>';
wp_kses($str, $allowed_html );
```

$str will actually receive a bunch of html tags and attributes from a post. Then from there i want to strip out all tags and attributes leaving out only divs tags and style and title attributes

Thank you, MMK.

Comment: Could you add a bit more on what exactly the problem is? What does `$allow_html` currently return that you want to change?

Comment: wp_kses strips out any tags and attributes leaving out only those specified in the parameter $allowed_html. The $str string contains a style attribute. I want to keep it. But instead wp_kses removes it. I want to know how i can keep the style attribute there.

Comment: $str will actually receive a bunch of html tags and attributes from a post. Then from there i want to strip out all tags and attributes leaving out only divs tags and style and title attributes

Comment: It may be easier for future readers to view if you edited your original question and added this information, so it's all together. That way it will be easier to answer. There's an edit button just underneath the tags.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is an older question, but here's the answer for future generations:

WordPress will check the styles against a list of allowed properties and it will still strip the `style` attribute if none of the styles are safe. The default allow list ([as of WordPress 6.2](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.2/wp-includes/kses.php#L2306C1-L2454)) is:

```php
array(
    'background',
    'background-color',
    'background-image',
    'background-position',
    'background-size',
    'background-attachment',
    'background-blend-mode',

    'border',
    'border-radius',
    'border-width',
    'border-color',
    'border-style',
    'border-right',
    'border-right-color',
    'border-right-style',
    'border-right-width',
    'border-bottom',
    'border-bottom-color',
    'border-bottom-left-radius',
    'border-bottom-right-radius',
    'border-bottom-style',
    'border-bottom-width',
    'border-bottom-right-radius',
    'border-bottom-left-radius',
    'border-left',
    'border-left-color',
    'border-left-style',
    'border-left-width',
    'border-top',
    'border-top-color',
    'border-top-left-radius',
    'border-top-right-radius',
    'border-top-style',
    'border-top-width',
    'border-top-left-radius',
    'border-top-right-radius',

    'border-spacing',
    'border-collapse',
    'caption-side',

    'columns',
    'column-count',
    'column-fill',
    'column-gap',
    'column-rule',
    'column-span',
    'column-width',

    'color',
    'filter',
    'font',
    'font-family',
    'font-size',
    'font-style',
    'font-variant',
    'font-weight',
    'letter-spacing',
    'line-height',
    'text-align',
    'text-decoration',
    'text-indent',
    'text-transform',

    'height',
    'min-height',
    'max-height',

    'width',
    'min-width',
    'max-width',

    'margin',
    'margin-right',
    'margin-bottom',
    'margin-left',
    'margin-top',
    'margin-block-start',
    'margin-block-end',
    'margin-inline-start',
    'margin-inline-end',

    'padding',
    'padding-right',
    'padding-bottom',
    'padding-left',
    'padding-top',
    'padding-block-start',
    'padding-block-end',
    'padding-inline-start',
    'padding-inline-end',

    'flex',
    'flex-basis',
    'flex-direction',
    'flex-flow',
    'flex-grow',
    'flex-shrink',
    'flex-wrap',

    'gap',
    'column-gap',
    'row-gap',

    'grid-template-columns',
    'grid-auto-columns',
    'grid-column-start',
    'grid-column-end',
    'grid-column-gap',
    'grid-template-rows',
    'grid-auto-rows',
    'grid-row-start',
    'grid-row-end',
    'grid-row-gap',
    'grid-gap',

    'justify-content',
    'justify-items',
    'justify-self',
    'align-content',
    'align-items',
    'align-self',

    'clear',
    'cursor',
    'direction',
    'float',
    'list-style-type',
    'object-fit',
    'object-position',
    'overflow',
    'vertical-align',

    'position',
    'top',
    'right',
    'bottom',
    'left',
    'z-index',
    'aspect-ratio',

    // Custom CSS properties.
    '--*',
)
```

This list is, as with most things in WordPress, filtered! You can add `display` to it as follows to let your code work as expected:

```
add_filter( 'safe_style_css', function( $styles ) {
    $styles[] = 'display';
    return $styles;
} );
```

Comment: For more info, see [`wp_kses_attr_check()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_attr_check/) and [`safecss_filter_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/safecss_filter_attr/).

Comment: @brooke thanks for the edit, you're the real mvp!

Comment: Dang, I wasted so much time on this. Thanks for your clear answer and solution. Still helping people 8 years later.